# conda update failed with CustomValidationError

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

guys:

When I update my conda, I met a custom validation error. Although I google a lot, I could not find any solutions.

If anyone has a solution for this problem, please help me!

Thanks

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update conda
>
> CustomValidationError: Parameter default_python = None declared in <> is invalid.default_python value 'None' not of the form '[23].[0-9]'
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update --all
>
> CustomValidationError: Parameter default_python = None declared in <> is invalid.default_python value 'None' not of the form '[23].[0-9]'

Comment: Sounds like your default python version is set to none, which doesn't meet the regex requirement.

Comment: so how to change the default set?